# Cannot call Ramsey\Uuid\Converter\Number\DegradedNumberConverter::toHex without support for large integers

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-nova, php-7.4

I am getting the following error in laravel/Nova

```
Cannot call Ramsey\Uuid\Converter\Number\DegradedNumberConverter::toHex without support for large integers, since integer is an unsigned 128-bit integer; Moontoast\Math\BigNumber is required. {"userId":35387,"exception":"[object] (Ramsey\\Uuid\\Exception\\UnsatisfiedDependencyException(code: 0): Cannot call Ramsey\\Uuid\\Converter\\Number\\DegradedNumberConverter::toHex without support for large integers, since integer is an unsigned 128-bit integer; Moontoast\\Math\\BigNumber is required. at /home/vagrant/sinbad/vendor/ramsey/uuid/src/Converter/Number/DegradedNumberConverter.php:52)
```

I am using below version.

php version : 7.4

laravel : 7

laravel nova : 3

Comment: DegradedNumberConverter throws `UnsatisfiedDependencyException` exceptions if attempting to use number conversion functionality in an environment that does not support large integers (i.e. when moontoast/math is not available) -- https://github.com/ramsey/uuid/issues/288

Answer (score 4):

It cannot process a long number (128 bits long) on a 32 bit system.
Install following package and that should resolve it.

```
composer require moontoast/math
```

You can also visit this thread to read the extra technical details
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/23291